# setting environment variables from command line inside unit files

Tags: environment-variables, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to set a date inside the unit file for logging

my unit file look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jetty service
After=multiuser.target

[Service]
Environment=MAIN_CLASS="com.candorgrc.nphase.MainJetty"
Type=simple
User=jetty
Group=jetty
WorkingDirectory=/home/jetty/dist
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/systemctl set-environment date=$(/bin/date +%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H-%%M)
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/jetty/logging.properties -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/u01/jetty/hdumps/hdump_${date} -verbose:gc -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12321 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authen
PIDFile=/var/run/jetty.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
#Restart=on-failure
ExecStop=/bin/kill -9 $MAINPID
```

Setting the date does not seam to be working. The error I get is the following:

```
Nov 26 16:47:50 vps203756 systemctl[14275]: Failed to set environment: Invalid environment assignments
Nov 26 16:47:50 vps203756 systemd[1]: jetty.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 26 16:47:50 vps203756 systemd[1]: jetty.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 26 16:47:50 vps203756 systemd[1]: Failed to start Jetty service.
```

Any idea how to configure it for it to work?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323914/dynamic-variables-in-systemd-service-unit-files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Commands in `ExecStart=` in systemd service units do not really run on a shell, so shell expansions (such as the command substitution `$(...)` you use there) are not really available.

You can use them by calling a shell script explicitly, with `/bin/sh -c '...'`, in your `ExecStartPre=`. For example:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'systemctl set-environment date=$$(/bin/date +%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H-%%M)'
```

Note that you need to escape the `$` itself, by using `$$`, otherwise systemd will try to interpret as a systemd variable expansion. (Actually, as the next character is `(`, a single `$` might work there, but doubling it is the more correct setup.)

Please note that using `systemctl set-environment` like you're doing is really not recommended, since you're creating a *global* environment variable `${date}` that will be available everywhere.

Instead, consider running your `ExecStart=` command through a shell, in which case you can define a shell variable `${date}` and just use it in the single place you need it:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'date=$$(/bin/date +%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H-%%M); exec java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m ... -XX:HeapDumpPath=/u01/jetty/hdumps/hdump_$${date} -verbose:gc ...
```

Note again, escaping the `$` with `$${date}`, so systemd doesn't think it's a systemd variable to expand. Also, using `exec` to ensure the shell is replaced with the `java` process, making sure systemd will know what the main PID of the service is.

Escaping on systemd `ExecStart=` can become complex and burdensome quite quickly... So consider instead storing the shell script in a file (in which case you don't need to worry about escaping `$` and `%` and about how the quotes might work slightly differently) and just run that script from the `ExecStart=`, that's a lot simpler (even though it requires an extra file...)